# Cannot add backgound view to under popup view using xib

Tags: ios, swift, popup

I'm create a custom modal for control show & dismiss animation with this tutorial https://medium.com/@aatish.rajkarnikar/how-to-make-custom-alertview-dialogbox-with-animation-in-swift-3-2852f4e6f311. Instead of draw a view programmatically, I use .xib file for faster layout making. But below is what I get. Where I'm wrong?

[image]

my .xib file:

[image]

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

protocol ModalAsPopup {
    func show(animated: Bool)
    func dismiss(animated: Bool)
    var backgroundView: UIView {get}
    var dialogView: UIView {get set}
}

extension ModalAsPopup where Self:UIView {
    func show(animated:Bool){
        self.backgroundView.alpha = 0
        if var topController = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController {
            while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
                topController = presentedViewController
            }
            topController.view.addSubview(self)
        }
        if animated {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.33, animations: {
                self.backgroundView.alpha = 0.66
            })
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.33, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 10, options: UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: 0), animations: {
                self.dialogView.center  = self.center
            }, completion: { (completed) in
                
            })
        }else{
            self.backgroundView.alpha = 0.66
            self.dialogView.center  = self.center
        }
    }
    
    func dismiss(animated:Bool){
        if animated {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.33, animations: {
                self.backgroundView.alpha = 0
            }, completion: { (completed) in
                
            })
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.33, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 10, options: UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: 0), animations: {
                self.dialogView.center = CGPoint(x: self.center.x, y: self.frame.height + self.dialogView.frame.height/2)
            }, completion: { (completed) in
                self.removeFromSuperview()
            })
        }else{
            self.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        
    }
}
```

And in my popup class I handle and create a backgroundView:

```
class CaptchaView: UIView, ModalAsPopup {
    var backgroundView = UIView()
    
    var dialogView = UIView()
    
    convenience init(title: String?, captchaImage: UIImage?, puzzleImage: UIImage?, yCoordinates: CGFloat) {
        self.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        initialize(title: title, captchaImage: captchaImage, puzzleImage: puzzleImage, yCoordinates: yCoordinates)
    }
    
    static func getCapchaView() -> CaptchaView {
        let nib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CaptchaView", owner: nil, options: nil)
        let view = nib?.first as! CaptchaView
        view.setupView()
        
        return view
    }
    
    private func setupView() {
        //Do something here
    }
    
    func initialize(title: String?, captchaImage: UIImage?, puzzleImage: UIImage?, yCoordinates: CGFloat) {
        dialogView.clipsToBounds = true
        
        backgroundView.frame = frame
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        backgroundView.alpha = 0.6
        backgroundView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapOnBackgroundView)))
        addSubview(backgroundView)
        
        dialogView.addSubview(self)

//Other code...
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain precisely what is not correct ? Could you show the xib file ?

Comment: where are you using `CaptchaView` ? and how you are creating that ?

Comment: @claude31 the not correct is I wanna show a background view behind my popup, then add a tap gesture on it to handle dismiss if click outside the popup. But as you see in the picture, the gray background is adding on my popup, not outside. 
@jawadAli I'm create with .xib file and calling CaptchaView in other UIViewController `self.captchaView.initialize(title: "abc"...) self.captchaView.show(animated: true)`

Comment: @Bad_Developer what I see on screen is a brown square. Is it what you want in background ? I do not either see the popup. Where is it ? Did you try to use view layers instead ?

Comment: @claude31 yes that is. I have to update the picture. My goal is the gray view must stay under of popup.

Comment: Yes, I'm updated.